# Technological choice for a mobile application

Tags: react-native, express, mobile, django-rest-framework

I will soon make a mobile application. For the front-end I will use React native and for the back-end I want to make an API but I don't know which technology to use, Django REST API, express js?

My problem is with regard to the videos to store, which technology is going to be the most suitable for storing them?

So, what technology would you use to create an API that can store videos properly and that will be called by react native?

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer to a question like this. It all depends on your expectations, experience, resources, time, etc. It is also a very subjective question because most developers have their own preferences about these solutions. The truth is that you can build a solution in A LOT of different ways. Besides the JS frameworks you suggest, popular choices are .NET, PHP, C#, Ruby, Java and Python... and much more!

Besides the backend / API, you will also need a server for hosting your API and maybe another type of server for storage.

If you want to build everything yourself, take a look at the services provided by [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/), [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/) or [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/). If you have limited experience building backends and want to save time, take a look at [Google Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) or [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/).

The last two are plug-and-play solutions for expecially mobile apps like the one you are describing.

Check it all out and make your own opinion!

Good luck with your project! :-)